# Does Amazon publish RDS IP Ranges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I cannot find any RDS IP ranges for Amazon, only EC2 ranges. At my company I am behind a firewall and proxy, and we do not allow for DNS rules. So while RDS has a static DNS endpoint, it is useless to me. I can only connect through IP ranges. I have only found public ranges for Amazon EC2.

Comment: Are you sure the EC2 ranges don't work? I would be surprised if RDS *isn't* run on top of the EC2 infrastructure.

Comment: I am not sure. I was assuming you are correct but I wanted to verify since I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The RDS service is basically using EC2 resources for the RDS instances therefore using the EC2 network IP ranges for the correct region should allow your communication to go through your firewall if/when the IP address for the RDS instance changes.

You would need to keep an eye this post in order to see if their are any new ranges added on a regular basis. You could use something like this to output to file and then diff the results to alert you if they are different.
Amazon EC2 Public IP Ranges
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701